# Django "autofocus" on form validation error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Using Django 1.9 and python 3.5,  I would like to "set focus" on the first field which fails validation in my modelform.

How is this accomplished?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work for you. (untested)

During your form's `__init___` iterate through the fields. Apply the `autofocus` attribute to the first field you encounter with an error.

```
class MyForm(models.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for _, field in self.fields.iteritems():
            if field in self.errors:
                field.widget.attrs.update({
                    'autofocus': ''
                })

                break
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #Focus on form field whenever error occurred
    errorList=list(self.errors)
    for item in errorList:
        self.fields[item].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': ''})
        break
```